# How can I have a link automatically redirect in PHP

Tags: php, redirect, hyperlink

I have a php form for users to create an account. When the submit button is pressed, the page is redirected to a response page that saves the information to a database. I have a link on the response page that sends the user to a page which displays the account information.

```
echo "<a href ='AccountInformation.php'>Account Information</a>";
```

How can I instead make the response page automatically redirect to the display page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy, you make :

```
header("location:AccountInformation.php");
```

before any output (echo, print, print_r, plain HTML ... ) is sent to the web browser.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response

Comment: just in case it comes up, you need to use this line of code before any output to the page has started too

Comment: @dstewart101 Really? I put  the code on the bottom of the page and it worked.

Comment: @user8272041 - yep, just like the edited answer from Lambda7 above says